# Find the most string value in a whole dataframe / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns each containing actor names.
The actors are present in several columns and I want to find the actor or actress most present in all the dataframe. 
I used mode and but it doesn't work, it gives me the most present actor in each column

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question so that we can help you.

Comment: You can try `df.stack().tolist()` and then apply your function on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to use the Counter class in python. Thereby, you can simply add whole rows and columns into the object. The code would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# Artifically creating DataFrame
actors = [
    ["Will Smith","Johnny Depp","Johnny Depp","Johnny Depp"],
    ["Will Smith","Morgan Freeman","Morgan Freeman","Morgan Freeman"],
    ["Will Smith","Mila Kunis","Mila Kunis","Mila Kunis"],
    ["Will Smith","Charlie Sheen","Charlie Sheen","Charlie Sheen"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(actors)

# Creating counter
counter = Counter()

# inserting the whole row into the counter
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    counter.update(row)

print("counter object:")
print(counter)

# We show the two most common actors
for actor, occurences in counter.most_common(2):
    print("Actor {} occured {} times".format(actor, occurences))
```

The output would look like this:

```
counter object:
Counter({'Will Smith': 4, 'Morgan Freeman': 3, 'Johnny Depp': 3, 'Mila Kunis': 3, 'Charlie Sheen': 3})
Actor Will Smith occured 4 times
Actor Morgan Freeman occured 3 times
```

The counter object solves your problem quite fast but be aware that the counter.update-function expects lists. You should not update with pure strings. If you do it like this, your counter counts the single chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` and `value_counts` to get the entire list of actors/actresses:

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

Using @Ofi91 setup:

```
# Artifically creating DataFrame
actors = [
    ["Will Smith","Johnny Depp","Johnny Depp","Johnny Depp"],
    ["Will Smith","Morgan Freeman","Morgan Freeman","Morgan Freeman"],
    ["Will Smith","Mila Kunis","Mila Kunis","Mila Kunis"],
    ["Will Smith","Charlie Sheen","Charlie Sheen","Charlie Sheen"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(actors)

df.stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Will Smith        4
Morgan Freeman    3
Johnny Depp       3
Charlie Sheen     3
Mila Kunis        3
dtype: int64
```

To find most number of appearances:

```
df.stack().value_counts().idxmax()
```

Output:

```
'Will Smith'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider your data frame to be like this

[image]

First we stack all columns to 1 column.
Use the below code to achieve that

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.stack().reset_index(drop=True))`

[image]

Now, take the value_counts of the actors column using the code

`df2 = df1['actors'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)`

[image]

Here you go, the resulting data frame has the actor name and the number of occurrences in the data frame.

Happy Analysis!!!